# Is it possible in android to leave an AlertDialog in front of changing Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have an app with multiple Activity classes. In one part, one is a main screen and the next is a login. The user would open the login screen and enter their info and press a button to submit it. The resulting code opens up an AlertDialog to tell them the registration status, along with some other information. If the registration itself was successful, they will return to the previous activity. But this makes any AlertDialog disappear with it.

I want the background to return to the previous activity so they can see the home page start updating, but I want them to see the alert message long enough to read it.

Comment: Are you want to navigate one activity to another activity when your alert dialog is on foreground ??

Comment: As CodeProcessor answered it can be done using service like `chatHeads` which you can see in facebook messenger app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possble. By using a service you can display an alertbox which runs in foreground for a long time. I have done thissame kind of thing for a news app.

It will run in foreground for a long time and when you want to switch you can stop the service than it will dismiss the alert box-.

In my case I displayed a custom view with buttons in the foreground.